# Input, and reading the input in SageMath

Tags: python, sage

I have been trying to develop a code in which the user inputs a function using `x` and `y` which is then read into an integral.  I tried using `eval`, and `sage_eval` but neither worked.

Here is my attempt:

```
y = var('y')
f(y) = eval(input("What is the function:"))
integral(f(y), y, 0, 16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
sage: y = var('y')
sage: f(y) = eval(input("What is the function: "))
What is the function: sin(y)
sage: integral(f(y), y, 0, 16)
-cos(16) + 1
```

Suggestion: read about SageCell, interacts, widgets.

Comment: It keeps saying name 'y' is not defined